# Where is the spec of HashCash so that I can implement it in Java from scratch?

Tags: hash, proof-of-work

I would like to implement HashCash in an efficient/fast/garbage-free way. Is there a spec to do so? How can someone go by implementing HashCash from scratch?

Comment: Not necessarily a spec, but possibly helpful for you: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hashcash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily answering your question, but I found a HashCash implementation in Java already here: https://github.com/ryancwilliams/JHashCash Perhaps you can contribute or fork it?